# MediaPlayer in service pauses after a while

Tags: android, service, android-mediaplayer

I have implemented a media player in a service and it works fine when i have a playlist is on as long as the screen is on. However, when the screen is locked, playback stops after  a couple of songs and i have to press play again in order to continue.

Is there anything that causes the service to stop or the media player to pause playback when the screen is off, even after I add a partial wake lock?